# what is meant by "holy cows" phrases?

Tags: phrases

When holy cows are used in the phrases? Any sample phrases with holy cow.
Also, the meaning of those phrases.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+holy-cow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase is also derived from the Brahman belief that cows are holy. I imagine the first group of Europeans who were told that their religion believed their cows were sacred stated with amazement such that they said "Holy Cow!?" And what they meant was: *You believe cows are holy?* It is used to convey disbelief in some cases: disbelief as in incredible, or not credible. After that it came to express amazement at something difficult to find credible. Can you imagine the response when the English captains sailed back to England and told their friends there was a group of people who worshiped cows?

Comment: Always try to cite the source.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true (though it seems intuitive). I can't find any sources verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you're asking for the meaning of the phrase "holy cow" :)

*Holy cow* is used as an informal exclamation of disbelief or surprise:

> "Holy cow, did you see that!?"
>
> "That was amazing! Holy cow!"

The meanings of these phrases are exactly as they would be without the "holy cow" bits; the "holy cow" is simply for emphasis.

It can also be used alone:

> "Holy cow!"

This is, as you'd expect, just an exclamation of surprise.

I have never seen it used any where but at the beginning of a statement (to prime it for effect) or on its own (as a simple exclamation).

*cow* is always singular, never plural. That is, never *holy cows*, always *holy cow*.

Some cursory investigation tells me that the phrase is a euphemism for "holy Christ" (first line of this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_cow_%28expression%29))